# Automatically run a webservice after git commit in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, automation, egit

I want to update the commit details to my server automatically after git commit in eclipse How to do it ?

Comment: After `commit` or after `push`?

Comment: After commit and push any thing would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really independent of Eclipse. The mechanism is the same whether you are doing `git commit` using Eclipse, Netbeans, or on the command line.

You need to install a [commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), either client side or server side depending on whether you want it after `commit` or `push`. Inside the hook script, you can do whatever you want, including talking to a web service and telling it about commit details.